# How to add a RowPadding to DataGridView?

Tags: c#, datagridview, custom-controls

I'm currently working on a groupable datagridview. All works fine, but now I want to add a padding to the left. In the picture below I'm using the rowheader and paint over it, but isn't there any other way?

[image: CustomDatagridView with Padding via RowHeader]

Comment: Why not target it through css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use another column, with a fixed width, the row-header hidden and the background-color set to the background-color of the grid.

Comment: im now using `RowHeadersWidthSizeMode = DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode.DisableResizing;` and paint the rowheader if necessary by my self, thanks again.